# Count the number of files with yesterday's date in ls's output

Tags: linux, date, command

I would like to count the number of files with yesterday's date in ls's output.
I tried:

```
yday=$(date --date="yesterday" +"%b%Oe")
ls . -ltr | grep $yday | wc -l
```

The problem is that files have dates with **two** spaces between the month and days less than 10, for example:

```
Jan  6
   ^^---- two spaces
```

but my command creates a date with only one space:

```
yday=$(date --date="yesterday" +"%b%Oe")

Jan 6
   ^----- one space
```

How can I modify my command to solve this problem?

Comment: You want the -mtime option to find. You'll need to calculate how long ago the day you want is and try something like "find `pwd` -mtime -1 -type f -print" You may refer to http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-finding-files-by-date/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
yday=$(date --date="yesterday" +"%b %_d")
```

to produce the string you want (the underscore says to pad with spaces)